# Using Google Cloud Messaging for Android

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification

I am looking for a way to receive notifications on Android and Iphone app.

For Android, after research I found of Google cloud messaging. I have understood briefly that this is a free service and allows unlimited sending of data to the device.

https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

When I check sdk manager I am unable to find Google cloud messaging for android package in Extras section. How do I update Eclipse settings so as to use this feature.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You only need the `Google Play Services` library from the Extras section. The GCM client library is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take update of Google Play Service from Android SDK "EXTRA" and then follow this link

https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Hi there **Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library** have been deprecated and now **Android Support Library** is used instead. And about your question of not seeing it in your SDK manager you can do the following:

1) Open **SDK manager**.

2) Goto to **Packages** option on the top-left corner.

3) Select **Show Obsolete Package**.

Now you will be able to see the package.